# GCM works on emulator and not on real device under company wifi proxy

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have been working on GCM,i have used gcm sample server from android developers site and latest GCM apis it works on emulator under wifi company proxy with ports enabled 5228,5229,5230 but not on real device following steps I have taken : 
1. Emulator enabled ports 5228,5229 n 5230 under wifi proxy for my machine. 
2. On real device I have assigned static ip and enabled gcm ports on firewall but still I am unable to get push messages on real device.

What settings needs to be done for company wifi proxy firewall to get push notification work
on real device I have tried on following device:
1. Samsung duos quadtrro
2. Canvas Micromax A116

Comment: Do you get any error or warning in logcat for real device?

Comment: On real device if "assigned static ip and enabled gcm ports on firewall" first of all I am not getting the registeration id i get error as "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE" but we give full internet access to real device then only gcm works on real device